# Parse a nested JSON in a list/array to display it in a table in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, json, lightning-datatable, jsongenerator

Below is my JSON and I want it to parse and display the contents in a table in LWC like below. I used the JSONtoApex tool to create the parser class but I am not getting in which format I should return my data to LWC jS file so that I can iterate the list/array and display the data in the format shown in below image? I am able to add the individual inner JSON elements (identity,policy..) in to list but I want them to be in a single datatype to be able to iterate in js

```
 ResultDataJsonParse obj = ResultDataJsonParse.parse(responseBody);
 List<ResultDataJsonParse.detail> detailsList = new List<ResultDataJsonParse.detail>();
 List<ResultDataJsonParse.contract> contractsList = new List<ResultDataJsonParse.contract>();
 for(ResultDataJsonParse.content con:obj.content ){
            detailsList.add(con.vehicle);   
        }
```

[image]

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "identity": {
        "caseId": "7546040",
        "caseType": "SMR"
      },
      "policy": {
        "createDate": "1669620011000",
        "modifyDate": "1670398216000",
        "statusCode": "NI"
      },
      "customer": {
        "customerId": "865208",
        "name": "KE PROTEZIONI SOLARI S.R.L."
      },
      "vehicle": {
        "registrationNumber": "FX446DX",
        "vehicleId": "AAFN3045"
      }
    },
    {
      "identity": {
        "caseId": "7546040",
        "caseType": "SMR"
      },
      "policy": {
        "createDate": "1669620011000",
        "modifyDate": "1670398216000",
        "statusCode": "NI"
      },
      "customer": {
        "customerId": "865208",
        "name": "KE PROTEZIONI SOLARI S.R.L."
      },
      "vehicle": {
        "registrationNumber": "FX446DX",
        "vehicleId": "AAFN3045"
      }
    }
  ],
  "first": "true",
  "numberOfElements": "22"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a parser class in this case. It is possible to directly pass this string to LWC and convert it to object/array in JS.

But if you want to use Apex then return it as a string from apex using below method :

```
System.JSON.serialize(detailsList);
```

In your LWC , just deserialise it using :

```
const data = JSON.parse(resultString);
```

Useful links :

- Apex Serialize -
  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_serialize
- JSON parse -
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: If I just return the json string after desrializing as below, I am getting first level of json but not the second level. 
In apex : `Map<String, Object> results =  (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(responseBody);  `

Here is what I am trying in js
`let contentDetails = result['content']; let identityDetails= contentDetails['identity'];` result is returned map from apex
The value for identityDetails is getting as undefined

Comment: @user59277 : result['content'] is an array as seen from your question.
Try with : contentDetails[0]['identity']

Comment: @ 42656 Thanks!!!  I am getting the data now but as [object,object]. it seems we retrived only the contenDetails which is at index 0. I have 22 such rows. So should I create an array variable `IdentityArray = [];` and add all details in a loop iterating it 22 times?

Comment: No , your content details are present in result['content'] which is an array. result['content'] is your required array. 
Please accept & upvote if this answer helped you. Welcome.

Comment: Or try this in your LWC : const IdentityArray = result['content'].map(ele => ele['identity']);

Comment: @user59277, does above answer help you ?

Comment: @45626 Yes, it really did help me.Thank you!!!

Comment: Thank you @user59277